# Is there a Windows API to set 16-byte array atomically?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, atomic

I was wondering if there's a windows API to set a 16-byte array atomically?

I would really hate to introduce critical sections or mutexes into this just to implement this operations, so I'm trying to find an easier solution.

PS. I need this because this 16-byte array can be written into from a worker thread, and mostly read from a main thread.

Comment: A 16-byte *array*? Meaning an indefinite number of 16-byte elements? That would basically mean an atomic operation that can set an arbitrary large chunk of memory, which does not exist.

Comment: How much time will it take to write critical section code? Not more than 5 minutes? And the PS in your question is just a useless piece of info.

Comment: @John Calsbeek No, I didn't mean that. I meant atomically copying those 16 bytes.

Comment: @Nawaz It would take me about 10 seconds to write an API. And that is a x30 gain... Again, I'm just probing to see if there's an API out there. If not, I'll stick with using mutexes.

Comment: If you just want to write one 16-byte quantity with full memory barriers, you could probably use `InterlockedExchange16`. I'm hesitant to recommend it, however, because I don't know anything about what you're doing and I doubt this will actually be problem-free.

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek:  That's 16 _bits_.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Ah, damn it, misread the question. The existence of `_InterlockedCompareExchange128` appears to suggest that the answer is "yes"... assuming that your data is aligned.

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek Thanks for the edit. 128 bits look exactly what I need. One thing makes me question it though. That MSDN article says, Architecture x64. Does it require a 64-bit CPU?

Comment: @ahmd0 Yes, it does require a 64-bit CPU. In fact, some earlier 64-bit CPUs from AMD don't even support it. And, of course, there's the problem that you need to know the previous value in those bytes, so a full atomic write would need to use the operation in a loop.

Comment: Very good. I just learned something. Why don't you post it as an answer and I'll mark it. Very interesting info. It seems like the "lock" on the copy operation is actually supported by the CPU itself (and not by the OS, like in case of critical sections and mutexes.) So those APIs would be perfect for 2 or 4 byte exchanges... Good find.

Comment: @ahmd0 Incidentally, if you want an atomic store that *doesn't* act as a memory barrier (you can always add barriers yourself), then you can use an aligned SSE store, which should also be atomic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the following assumes a 64-bit x86_64 architecture. I believe that in general what you asked for is not possible on 32-bit x86.

There are really two options. The first one is [`_InterlockedCompareExchange128`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514094.aspx), which translates to `LOCK CMPXCHG16B`. To duplicate the functionality of a 16-byte store with it, you'd need to do something like this:

```
__int64* dest = ...;
__int64* orig = ...;
unsigned char ok;
do
{
    __int64 high = dest[0];
    __int64 low  = dest[1];
    ok = _InterlockedCompareExchange128(dest, high, low, orig);
}
while (!ok);
```

Note that because this is an interlocked operation, it implies the equivalent of a [`_ReadWriteBarrier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f20w0x5e.aspx). This is normally what is meant by an "atomic" operation.

If you want a pure store, not a compare-exchange, then you can use anything that translates to an aligned 16-byte store on the hardware. For example, the `MOVDQA` instruction would qualify. In C++, that'd look something like this:

```
__m128i* dest = ...;
_mm_mfence();
_mm_store_si128(dest, _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&orig));
_mm_mfence();
```

Unless you have a reason to avoid SSE instructions, I think the second version might perform better. You also may want to decide if you want to relax the two memory barriers depending on your actual needs.

Comment: I wish there were an "objectPair" type in .net which held two object references and could be CompareExchanged.  Since 32-bit machines have 32-bit object references and a 64-bit compare-exchange, and 64-bit machines have 64-bit object references but a 128-bit compare exchange, it would seem that it should be possible for .net to allow a CompareExchange of a pair of object references.  Not as useful as a true double-compare-and-swap operation as found on the 68020, but available on today's hardware.